# VisualStudio 2013 - debugging on Remote Machine error

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run my blank Windows Store Application using "Remote Machine" from VisualStudio 2013.

I installed Remote Tools x86( 64 doesn't work) for VS 2013 on Tablet ( Windows 8, Intel Atom).
After clicking Start Debgging in VS2013 incoming connection is shown in  Remote Debugging Monitor on Tablet, but I get an Error:

```
(..)
2>------ Deploy started: Project: store (Windows 8.1), Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Error : DEP0600 : The following unexpected error occurred during deployment: 
2>Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: That error seems to be XML related. Does the app run fine locally? Check your store association file first, I'd say. Next, your app manifest.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a new created, blank application. Locally works Ok